# When running the shell script in EC2 user data the whole script is runs perfectly other then the git commands

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, user-data

i have an ec2 instance and i'm trying to create auto scaling group and i'm trying to to give a Customized AMI and i just wanted whenever the auto scaling group create new server it already have my latest code and and runs a commands or shell script. so i'm giving a predefined user data or shell script.
i'm facing a problem when auto scaling group create the image it executes most of the commands but it cannot git clone the project from my github repository and when i manually git clone the project it works fine. i already uploaded the public and private key in my base AMI and Github account.

following are the my script which i'm trying to run in user data

```
#! /bin/sh
git clone mygithubrepository
cd backend
git checkout mybranch
cd src 
sudo cat > ecosystem.config.js <<- "EOF"
module.exports = {
 apps : [{
  name: 'API',
  script: 'server/server.js',
  args: 'one two',
  instances: 4,
exec_mode:'cluster',
  autorestart: true,
  watch: false,
  max_memory_restart: '16G',
  env: {
   NODE_ENV: 'dev',
   CLOUDWATCH_GROUP_NAME:"Staging",
   CLOUDWATCH_ACCESS_KEY: my access key
   CLOUDWATCH_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:secret access key,
   CLOUDWATCH_REGION: "ap-south-1",
   SERVER_NAME: "Staging Backend",
   ENABLE_CLOUDWATCH_LOGGING: true
  }
  }],
 deploy : {
  production : {
   user : 'node',
   host : 'my ip address',
   ref : 'origin/master',
   repo : 'my repo`enter code here`',
   path : '/var/www/production',
   'post-deploy' : 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production'
  }
}
}
EOF
```

when i run the above script in user data it only create following file not git clone the github repo.

Comment: when i run manually run git clone command on my machine it runs perfectly.

Comment: You should check the `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` after your EC2 starts to see why it cloud not clone the repo.

Comment: i checked it but can't understand it.